# Is it appropriate to edit out this odd bit of self promotion answering edited into a question?

Tags: discussion, editing, questions

I recently came across [this question](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/1205/3168).  Despite the author of the question needing help automating their grading, they are also apparently an author of an automatic grading platform themselves.  The question in its original form made it look like the author was just a TA who needed help speeding up their grading process, but they've since edited what is essentially a kind of link only answer into their own post. The question now contains a list of links to auto grading platforms, with the first link being a link to their own.  Originally it seemed that they only listed [their own platform](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/revisions/1205/3).

I feel like this could be some how construed as useful information, but doesn't seem like it belongs in the question itself.

Can this kind of information be removed from the post entirely?  Others seem to have pointed out this issue, but instead of removing this information, they simply included more links in an effort to be more "fair"?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for pointing that out. I hadn't noticed that edit!

I removed the edit, and invited OP to post an answer if they so choose. They disclosed their affiliation, so it wasn't breaking any rules. However, it was somewhat bad behavior in that OP was ignoring the answer and voting process to put their own autograder right at the top.